# JavaFX Default Button keeps firing events

Tags: javafx-8

I have a button in my UI that I would like to be a "default button".  My understanding is that when I set the "defaultButton" property to true, the button will automatically capture the ENTER key and call my function.

```
    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add" onAction="#addToList"
                styleClass="icon-button, icon-add-dark" defaultButton="true" />
```

This definitely works BUT with one HUGE caveat: it fires the event no fewer than 4 times.  So every time I press ENTER once, I get 4 calls to "addToList"

The way that the handler is defined, the "addToList" function takes no parameters, so there's no event for me to "cancel propagation" on.

Am I missing something very simple? Am I just going about this the wrong way? All I'd like is to define the primary button on a form that will trigger when pressing ENTER. I'd like the event to only fire once per button press.

Comment: There are many possible things that could cause this; we just have to guess (e.g. your `addToList()` method is incorrectly implemented, or, possibly, you have other events mapped to the same handler). Create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: I agree James. Apologies for posting what appear to be a vague question.  In my initial evaluation of the issue, it really did just seem like: "Welp, I have this button and when I make it a default button and hit Enter, I get 4 invocations of my method". In reality, the 4 invocations would only happen if Enter was pressed while the cursor was in a custom auto-complete component.  That component extended ComboBox and the ComboBoxBehaviors and there I found my issues. I can post the example, but it's pretty specific so I'm not sure if anyone would be interested.